# Getting 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).timeago is not a function'

Tags: javascript, jquery

To calculate the relative time of a post I'm using jquery-timeago library. Here is the JavaScript code which I need to place in the HTML page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     $("abbr.timeago").timeago();
   });
</script>
```

I have also included Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Im still getting the error as

[image]

How do I resolve this error? There are already few questions such as this on Stack Overflow but none of them could resolve my issue.

EDIT:

Here's the head part of the HTML page

```
 <html>

<head>
    {% for ud in userdata %}
    <title>{{ud.fullname}} </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timeago/1.4.3/jquery.timeago.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("abbr.timeago").timeago();
    });
    </script>

</head>
```

Here's a fiddle. But it works fine. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8h8djqh6/10/)

EDIT : The issue has been resolved by making changes in the below way!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j("abbr.timeago").timeago();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: have you added `timeago` after `jQuery` ?

Comment: Yeah! I have added 'timeago'. And one more thing, I get this kind of error for every function I add, not just timeago. I mean to say, I get this error whenever I  use Jquery!

Comment: placing the script at the end of the body too didn't resolve the issue @MLM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace your current CDN with the below one and try.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timeago/1.4.3/jquery.timeago.js

Comment: download the files, and include in the script.

Comment: these must be reasons : Check weather jQuery id defined of not, there would have a conflict, use this  var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j("abbr.timeago").timeago();
    });

Comment: Thank You @Shussain. `var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); $j(document).ready(function() { $j("abbr.timeago").timeago(); });` This helped me in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Include this after jquery.min.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timeago/1.4.3/jquery.timeago.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Exactly same. JsFiddle works fine (https://jsfiddle.net/8h8djqh6/10/). But issue occurs only in the project.

Comment: did you put this after jquery.min.js and before the .timeago function called?

Comment: And don't use github link as a cdn it will create issue.

Comment: Yeah! Okay. I have updated the HEAD part of the code in the question details.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle now [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8h8djqh6/11/)

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2011-12-17T09:24:17Z">December 17, 2011</abbr>
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   $("abbr.timeago").timeago();
 });
```

Place your code properly. 
Then it will start working.

[CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timeago/1.4.3/jquery.timeago.js)

Use the CDN provided by [Shussain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3327698/shussain)

Comment: I have placed the same now. But same error. I also tried downloading files and including them in the code. Still same error. And yeah, I get this error whenever I try to use Jquery. Not just with `timeago`

Comment: Where You're getting the error? in your machine or jsfiddle ?

Comment: Fiddle is working fine. I get the error in my project!

Comment: have you added any other library that may conflict with `jQuery` ? or any other javascript library ? like `angular` ?

Comment: No. You can find HEAD part of the HTML page in the question details.

Comment: That things won't impact. Please go through your code line by line. and check are you missing anything? you must be missing something. Otherwise fiddle would not be working :P

Answer (score 0):

I had related issue, as per above in this exact case it was solved with Shussain user's comment:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict(); $j(document).ready(function() { $j("abbr.timeago").timeago(); });
```

But I have solved issue with replacing document ready as per below:

```
  (function ($) {
      "use strict"; 
      // Your js code

      });
    })(jQuery);
```